# PHPMyAdmin cannot be located on the server?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, cpanel

I am unable to locate the files for phpMyAdmin on my server. The hosting providers have given me a cPanel access. There is no /usr visible even from the admin user.
I want to edit some files manually, primarily configuration files for PHPMyAdmin like:
phpmyadmin/libraries/dbi/mysql.dbi.lib.php

I want to do this in order to fix Unicode text appearance issues. My Japanese strings are showing correctly on the MySQL console, but PHPMyAdmin messes them up. (I guess turning to latin1 or something). The collation and charset have been correctly set now. By editing these PHPMyAdmin files locally, I have achieved the desired results.

So, how can I locate the files ?

Regards !

Answer (score 0):

PHPMyAdmin for cPanel is located here and is only able to edit by `root`

```
/usr/local/cpanel/base/3rdparty/phpMyAdmin/
```